# How to Auto Slide Image Gallery?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I Followed the tutorial below to create a image gallery it works great but there is to things wrong with it

```
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/gallery/
```

1. I Need the Width to fill parent and height to wrap content

I Tried changing the 150,100

```
i.LayoutParameters = new Gallery.LayoutParams (150, 100);
```

but it still cant get it to work anyone have any ideas?

2. How can i auto slide the images
   i Tried adding a timer and do this but have no idea

I am also using Xamarin to create this

Answer (score 0):

Gallery is deprecated now, It is no longer maintain by Google/Android so its not the best to use this.
 You can follow step by step this

http://javatechig.com/android/android-viewflipper-example

it will solve all your problem